# How do I translate HTML code into normal text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ascii

I want to translate an input from an API like this

```
    <p>Communication that doesn&#8217;t take a chance doesn&#8217;t stand a chance.</p>
```

into something like this

"Communication that doesn’t take a chance doesn’t stand a chance."

I understand that html could translate this but I don't know how to translate this directly for use in javascript

Comment: @MikeC But that was answered with jquery.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Read further. There are other answers in vanilla JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert it into an element as HTML, and read it back out as text.

```
var elt = document.createElement('div');
elt.innerHTML = apiResponse;
alert(elt.textContent);
```